# Doing a Reality Show

Tags: reality-tv

Hi there. I need to do a reality show where there will be about 25 contestants and a presenter. Question is do I mic them all with lapels or boom? It will be alot of people moving around too.

If I mic them all, what do I record to?

Comment: can you provide more information about the show? indoor/outdoor? physically oriented? are there environmental concerns (i.e. water)? how much interaction between contestants? any additional info you can share (without getting yourself into trouble, of course) will net you more detailed and thoughtful responses.

Answer (score 1):

I personally can't be of much help but you probably want to do a little search [here](http://jwsoundgroup.net/)

Cheers